# Функция которая принимает два аргумента

Tags: javascript

Функция которая принимает три аргумента и возвращает true если все сложенные цифры четные

в чем проблема моего кода?

```js
let c = 0
let x = 1
let y = 1
let z = 2

function equal(x, y, z) {
  c += x + y + z
  if (x + y + z % 2 == 0) {
    console.log(c)
  } else {
    console.log(false)
  }
}
equal()
```

Comment: Вы опять? `equal(x, y, z)`

Comment: @Igor, интересно сколько же дальше...

Comment: Еще 12 :D, если бы кто то в личном чате обьяснил я бы больше не писал здесь :D

Comment: Проблема как минимум в том, что Вы ничего не возвращаете

Comment: Заходите, объясню https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117421/test-123

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let x = 1;
let y = 1;
let z = 2;

function equal(x, y, z) {
  c = x + y + z;
  if (c % 2 === 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
console.log(equal(x, y, z))
```

Comment: Можно просто `return c % 2 === 0`, либо даже `return !(c & 1)`

Comment: можно, но так будет понятнее для него